# How to set element id based on index in for-each loop?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to link text boxes and check boxes in a loop.
The problem I have is that all check boxes are linked to the first textbox because of link between the text box id and the checkbox name.
I read that I can get the index of the loop from using position(). But how can I get the value of position and concatenate it to the id and name of the text box and checkbox?

Any suggestions?

```
<xsl:for-each select="plants">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id= "plantName" name="//pn:plants/pn:plantName" disabled="disabled" maxlength="16"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="plantName"/> Edit name
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>           
            </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Does `<input type="checkbox" name="plantName{position()}"/>` do what you want? You might want to show us the relevant XML input and the corresponding HTML result sample you want to create with XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That did the trick :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can you post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it? Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an attribute value template in the form of `<input type="checkbox" name="plantName{position()}"/>` to compute the name as a concatenation of the static string `plantName` and the current value of `position()`.